# Numerical Integration of area defined by set of coordinates?

Tags: computational-geometry, numerical-methods, calculus, numerical-analysis, numerical-integration

Suppose you have a general shape defined by a bunch of coordinate points that form something that looks like a circle, ellipse, or general closed curve - how do you find the area bounded by these points?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I calculate the surface area of a 2d polygon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451426/how-do-i-calculate-the-surface-area-of-a-2d-polygon)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Find the [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms) of the set of points. Record down the points at the boundary.
2. Compute the [area of the polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula) bounded by those points.

If those points may not define a convex polygon, you need a [concave hull](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/concave-hull-definition-algorithms-and-practical-solutions) algorithm in step 1.

Comment: I like the elegant idiot-proof formula for general area for a polygon - what if you don't find the convex hull before applying that formula?

Comment: @ina: What do you want to apply to if you don't find the hull?

Comment: "rough" area inside a fractal brownian island

Answer (score 0):

you would typically use Monte Carlo integration or integration on the grid for multidimensional integration. you can adapt the same approach for flat surface as well.

Comment: I wish it were as easy as Monte Carlo -- but because you don't have an easy curve - it's a set of random data points, that roughly form a continuous curve - it's not easy to check for if something is bounded within.

Comment: You can use the crossing test to see if a point is inside or outside. Pick a point far away and your target point, then test against each contour segment to see if the test line segment crosses. If your crossing count is odd, you are inside, otherwise outside. (There are faster tests, if you know more about your shape.)