# Calculate the volume from a sequence of points in N^2

Tags: algorithm

Given a sequence of `(integer, integer)` points, say `(p1, ..., pn)`, which define the lines `(p_i, p_i+1)` for `1 <= i < n`, plus the line `(p_n, p_1)`. The resulting lines have the additional property that they don't intersect pairwise. What would be the best way to calculate the resulting volume?

Comment: Just to clarify: You are asking for an algorithm to calculate the area of a 2D polygon, right? Have you looked at the relevant [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon#Area_and_centroid)?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451426/how-do-i-calculate-the-surface-area-of-a-2d-polygon.

Comment: @thiton thanks for pointing to the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a nice code blurb with explanations as to why it works: http://alienryderflex.com/polygon_area/

```
//  Public-domain function by Darel Rex Finley, 2006.

double polygonArea(double *X, double *Y, int points) {

  double  area=0. ;
  int     i, j=points-1  ;

  for (i=0; i<points; i++) {
    area+=(X[j]+X[i])*(Y[j]-Y[i]); j=i; }

  return area*.5; }
```

You should also read the previous incarnation of this question: [How do I calculate the area of a 2d polygon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451426/how-do-i-calculate-the-surface-area-of-a-2d-polygon)