# Area of polygon using c++?

Tags: c++, polygon, area

How can i calculate the *area* of a *polygon* in c++ only by knowing the x and y coordonates of the points which make the polygon?

Comment: This is more a question for Math SE imo. Even then, you haven't shown any effort.

Comment: (1) Work out how you would do it on a piece of paper. (2) Translate into computer program. (3) Success!

Comment: **(4):** if !(3) post your question here.

Comment: @MarounMaroun, `!(3)` is always false, though :p

Comment: @chris sadly, he'll never post questions here xD

Comment: if it helps somebody: I answered it here.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/43174368/3719699

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple google search shows the answer provided that you are dealing with non-self-intersecting polygons. The sign of the area is positive if the points on the polygon are arranged in counterclockwise order. This formula does not assume that the polygon is convex.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygonArea.html

Here, the area is found by summing the determinent of neighboring points. Each determinent computes the area of the parallelogram formed by the vector e.g. (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) (where both vectors stem from the origin (0,0)). The division by 2 gives the area of a triangle. When traveling around the polygon, the triangles will have a positive area if your polygon is convex. Otherwise, negative areas of these triangles will cancel with their positive counterparts for the case of a concave polygon giving you the correct result.

Comment: No, convexity is not needed. Only absent of self intersection.

Comment: It's -ve for clockwise ordered points.

Comment: Sorry, I just corrected my mistake. Thank you @QuentinUK.

Answer (score 0):

Simple wikipedia search shows the answer:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon#Area_and_centroid