# Convex hull area in Python?

Tags: python, geometry, convex-hull

I have a set of points `A`. I get the convex hull `CH_A` of `A`.

Then, I have extra points, point set `B`. I add `B` into `A` and get a bigger point set. I obtain the convex hull `CH_AB` of this bigger set containing both `A` and `B`.

I want to quantify how much I have to pay to add `B` into set `A`. I am thinking about using an additional area to quantify this cost.

Say `CH_A` has an area of `Area_A`, then `CH_AB` has an area of `Area_AB`. Then, I want to calculate the marginal cost as

```
(Area_AB - Area_A) / Area_A
```

**How may I get the area of the convex hull in Python?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Convex hull** is simply a **convex polygon** so you can easily try [{this}](http://alienryderflex.com/polygon_area/) or [{this}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451426/how-do-i-calculate-the-surface-area-of-a-2d-polygon) to find area of 2D polygon.

Something like the following (our version):

```
def PolyArea2D(pts):
    lines = np.hstack([pts,np.roll(pts,-1,axis=0)])
    area = 0.5*abs(sum(x1*y2-x2*y1 for x1,y1,x2,y2 in lines))
    return area
```

in which pts is array of polygon's vertices i.e., a (nx2) array.

**Full usage:**

```
import numpy as np

def PolyArea2D(pts):
    lines = np.hstack([pts,np.roll(pts,-1,axis=0)])
    area = 0.5*abs(sum(x1*y2-x2*y1 for x1,y1,x2,y2 in lines))
    return area

pts = [[0,0],[1,0],[1,1],[0,1]]
print PolyArea2D(pts)    

pts = [[0,0],[1,0],[0,1]]
print PolyArea2D(pts)    

pts = [[0,0],[1,0],[0.5,0.5]] 
print PolyArea2D(pts)    

>>>
1.0
0.5
0.25
```

Comment: nice and clear answer. One issue though: the function name starts with an uppercase! :-)

Comment: If I give add a point that's inside the bigger polygon, the answer would change. Say,
`pts = [[0,0],[1,0],[1,1],[0,1]]
print PolyArea2D(pts) #1.0`

but

`pts = [[0,0],[1,0],[1,1],[0,1],[0.5,0.5]]
print PolyArea2D(pts)  #0.75`

Comment: I see this algorithm computing the area of a polygon given its vertices, but where does it compute the complex hull?

Answer (score 33):

You could just use the [`ConvexHull`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html) class from [`scipy.spatial`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.html). It will not only give you the hull's area, but it will compute the hull for you as well. But if you do use it, **BEWARE!** In 2D, the attribute you want to use is not *`area`*, it is *`volume`*, because the former will actually give you the hull's perimeter.

That's because the attributes are named after their values in 3D, where *`area`* will indeed be the hull's area, and *`volume`*, well, its volume. For 2D hulls, the names are the same, but what they actually contain is not quite what it says on the tin. Worse, the documentation does not warn you about this.

(You can easily check this with trivial examples such as an isosceles right triangle of length 1 on its legs: the perimeter should be 2+sqrt(2), or about 3.414213562, and the area should be 0.5.)