# NetLogo - calculating area of convex hull

Tags: netlogo

Agents in my model add patches to their territory patch-set. I'd like to calculate the area of the convex hull for their territories. However I am really having trouble figuring out how to implement those functions in the model. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why the area of the convex hull? Why not just the area of their territories (which is incredibly easy to calculate)?

Comment: @Bryan Head Because I'd like to compare territory size model results to results from various field studies that calculated minimum convex polygons.

Comment: There's probably a lot of convex-hull code out there for other languages; you might be able to translate something to NetLogo line by line.

Comment: Right here on stackoverflow, area of a convex hull (i.e. convex polygon) in Python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873596/convex-hull-area-in-python. This presumes you've already figured out the actual hull. But if all you have is a set of patches, you'll still need to figure out the span of the hull itself. It's really too bad you can't just count the patches (this would assume that the patches in the territories are all adjacent) to get the area.

Comment: Actually the patches are all adjacent or touching each other. The territory procedure actually discards a patch or group of patches if they are not contiguous to the largest group of patches. Sometimes the territory can have 'tendrils' or other odd arrangements that inflate the convex hull area calculation.

Comment: In that case, the area would be simply "count territory-patches" though that would give each patch an area of 1 unit. On the other hand, a complex hull made by connecting the patch centers would always have a smaller area. For example, the end of of a tendril would only count the area of the patch inside the "pointy bit" of the tendril!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the answer provided to the same question for Python:

```
to-report convex-hull-area [ #hull ]
   ;; #hull is an agentset of links,
   ;; presumably defining a complete hull
   report (.5 * abs ( 
     sum [ 
            [ xcor ] of end1 * [ ycor ] of end2 
          - [ xcor ] of end2 * [ ycor ] of end1
         ] of #hull
   )
end
```

It's easy using links, but you could also do something similar for sets of paired patches, or turtles, or an ordered list. MAP and REDUCE may be helpful there.

Comment: Thanks. This gives me something to work with. I'll try implementing it and see what happens. I still have to figure out how to determine which patches describe the convex hull.