# Finding largest closed 3D contour plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a scatter plot and many contour plots. There are many contours,some closed some not. How can I identify the values of the largest closed contour from [this].[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oejhs.jpg)

Comment: How do you define how large a closed contour is? Largest distance between any two points? Length?

Comment: the largest peripheral distance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding the biggest closed contour can be done as follows; note though that this assumes that by "biggest" you meant largest point-to-point distance.

Other size metrics could be easily substituted in though.

Note also that if you use the `extend3d=True` version, you would need to manipulate the `Poly3DCollection` that get's created which is a little more tricky.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d, art3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix
import numpy as np    

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
X, Y, Z = axes3d.get_test_data(0.05)
cset = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
ax.clabel(cset, fontsize=9, inline=1)

maxsize = 0
# Iterate over all the contour segments and find the largest
for i, segs in enumerate(cset.allsegs):
    for j, seg in enumerate(segs):
        # First make sure it's closed
        if (seg[0]-seg[-1]).any():
            continue
        # Now get it's size
        size = distance_matrix(seg, seg).max()
        if size > maxsize:
            maxsize = size
            maxseg = (i, j)

# Now highlight the "biggest" closed contour
cset.collections[maxseg[0]].set_color('y')
cset.collections[maxseg[0]].set_lw(5)
pts2d = cset.allsegs[maxseg[0]][maxseg[1]]
z = cset.levels[maxseg[0]]
coords = np.c_[ pts2d, z*np.ones(pts2d.shape[0]) ]
print(coords)

plt.show()
```

This results in:

[image]

Comment: thanks @jmetz. Is there a chance to get the datapoints in this contour. .I mean x,y,z co-ordinates?

Comment: np - data points are contained in the `seg` variables (they're 2d) and the z value is in the corresponding element of `cset.levels`.

Comment: I've updated the code to store them as `x,y,z` in the variable `coords`.

Comment: @user6457831 - don't forget to accept the answer if you're happy with it ;)

Comment: .Sure I was actually waiting to get this . Thanks a lot.Great work.Keep going

Comment: Just to know ,can we  also find the largest contour by "AREA" ??? Now its point to point distance.  @jmetz

Comment: @user6457831 - you could add in a polygon area calculation, e.g. `def PolyArea(x,y):
    return 0.5*np.abs(np.dot(x,np.roll(y,1))-np.dot(y,np.roll(x,1)))` from http://stackoverflow.com/a/30408825/537098