# Polygon of $n$ points: Area is easy, perimeter is hard?

Tags: python, geometry, polygon

I am in the situation that I have $n$ boundary points of a polygon in the plane.

Then, there is an explicit formula the so-called Shoelace formula to compute the area of the polygon

[Fastest way to Shoelace formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41077185/fastest-way-to-shoelace-formula)

The nice property is that the boundary points do not have to be ordered.

However, I am wondering if there also exists a similar simple algorithmtic way to compute the perimeter of the polygon just from the set of (possibly unordered) boundary points?

Comment: Isn't the perimeter just the sum of the lengths of the line segments?

Comment: sure but if I give you just the boundary points without telling you which one is connected to which, I am not sure how one would do it then...

Comment: In that case the polygon is underspecified. You *must* specify the order or you have not given the polygon a topology. Unless you want to define the area and perimeter of the "convex hull" of the polygon, for example.

Comment: @CoryKramer yes, we are indeed then talking about the convex hull

Comment: In that case [Graham scan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan) is a fairly popular convex hull algorithm, and pretty simple to code. Once you have the convex hull, then you just sum the lengths of the edges.

Comment: Then grab Scipy for computing the convex hull: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html