# JS - How much an irregular polygon covers an area

Tags: javascript, computational-geometry

**INTRO**
I have an **array** of **X/Y coordinates**. This array generates an **irregular polygon** inside a square area of 128 x 128 pixels. So the value of the coordinates can be only a number from 0 to 127 (0,0 is the left top corner - 127,127 is the right bottom corner).
I have *virtually* divided this area in **4 small areas** of 64 x 64 pixel each.

**QUESTION**
I would like **to calculate 4 percentages** where each percentage tells me how much the polygon is covering one of the **small areas**.

To be clear, I've this screenshot:

[image]

- A, B, C and D area the small areas.
- The red dots are the X/Y coordinates I have in an array.
- The green area is the polygon virtually generated by the coordinates.

So, how to calculate the percentages of the areas covered by the polygon? For example, looking the screenshot, I would like to obtain that the A area is 40% covered, the B area is 5% covered, the C area is 15% covered, the D area is 80% covered.

Does anyone know a Javascript script that can perform this kind of calculation? Honestly, I'm not good in geometry!

Comment: Your question is rather broad. I suggest narrowing it down a little. Consider just asking how to calculate the area of a polygon. See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467972/calculate-area-of-polygon-given-x-y-coordinates

Comment: If you want I can translate the answer in to javascript for you.

Comment: Thank for your help. I've read the link you provided, but that post is how to calculate the area of a polygon that's not my question... however, any help is very appreciated.

Comment: I'm not so sure how to do this with Javascript (OOP is awkward). How about some C# code?

Comment: Your task is fundamentally in two parts. The first task is to divide your polygon into 4 polygons, One for each quadrant of your grid. Then you need to calculate the area of those 4 individual polygons. You can then divide each of those areas from the area of the quadrant and find the percent.

Comment: Draw the polygon into a 128x128 bitmap. Then, count the pixels set in overy one of the fourth 64x64 zones.