# Computing the area filled by matplotlib.pyplot.fill(...)

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'd like to compute the area inside of a curve defined by two vectors `a` and `b`. For your reference the curve looks something like this (`pyplot.plot(a,b)`):

[image: curve to compute area]

I saw matplotlib has a [fill](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill.html) functionality that let you fill the area enclosed by the curve:

[image]

I'm wondering, there's any way to obtain the area filled using that same function? It would be very useful as the other way I'm thinking of computing that area is through numerical integration, much more cumbersome.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I calculate the area of a 2d polygon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451426/how-do-i-calculate-the-area-of-a-2d-polygon)

Comment: You can use Shapely for that. Or polygon3, I think.

Comment: [Calculate area of polygon given (x,y) coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467972/calculate-area-of-polygon-given-x-y-coordinates)

Comment: With shapely: [How to calculate area of polygon from list of points with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47657795/how-to-calculate-area-of-polygon-from-list-of-points-with-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to find the area that was filled by matplotlib.pyplot.fill(a, b), you can use its output as follows:

```py
def computeArea(pos):
    x, y = (zip(*pos))
    return 0.5 * numpy.abs(numpy.dot(x, numpy.roll(y, 1)) - numpy.dot(y, numpy.roll(x, 1)))

# pyplot.fill(a, b) will return a list of matplotlib.patches.Polygon.
polygon = matplotlib.pyplot.fill(a, b)

# The area of the polygon can be computed as follows:
# (you could also sum the areas of all polygons in the list).
print(computeArea(polygon[0].xy))
```

This method is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30408825),
and it is not the most efficient one.