# Area of voronoi cells within a given region

Tags: python, python-3.x, area, voronoi

I have the problem that I want to generate a Voronoi diagram in Python 3.8 and in a certain area (Orange) I want to know the sizes of the regions. What is the fastest way to do this?

[My Voronoi-Diagram with the bounding in orange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6nxO.png)

For the diagram I used scipy.spatial Voronoi and voronoi_plot_2d

Comment: Do you have the coordinates of the points?

Comment: Of cours! [(0.2, 0.1), (0, 1), (0.9, 1), (1, 0), (0.22, 0.2), (0.4, 0.18), (0.29, 0.22), (0.5, 0.4),  (0.2, 0.5), (0.9, 0.1)] But the points are only for illustration. It's about the general way because later I have a random number and position of the points.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467972/calculate-area-of-polygon-given-x-y-coordinates

Comment: Thanks! Now the only question is how I calculate the area within my boundaries. So within the orange area?

Comment: Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: If you could use a Java-based solution, there is a class called the BoundedVoronoiDiagram in the open-source Tinfour library that addresses your problem directly..  http://tinfour.org