# Python - Is there a method to calculate the signed area of a polygon?

Tags: python, methods, polygon, area, signed

I have a polygon defined in a Python list with (x, y) coordinates.

```
# for example
polygon = [(0, 0), (2, 0), (2, 2), (1, 1), (0, 2)]
```

I would like to get the signed area of this polygon. I know I could write my own algorithm to do it, but I'm searching for an existing method which does the same thing.

I've already read the following post : [Calculate area of polygon given (x,y) coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467972/calculate-area-of-polygon-given-x-y-coordinates) but it only talks about getting the area, which differs from the signed area.

Comment: The answer to that question is actually giving you the signed area. It’s just that the area and the signed area are equal, under the right conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To calculate the signed area of a polygon, you can use the shoelace formula. this code:

```
polygon = [(0, 0), (2, 0), (2, 2), (1, 1), (0, 2)]

def signed_polygon_area(polygon):
    n = len(polygon)
    area = 0.0
    for i in range(n):
        j = (i + 1) % n
        area += polygon[i][0] * polygon[j][1]
        area -= polygon[j][0] * polygon[i][1]
    return 0.5 * area

 print(signed_polygon_area(polygon)) --> 3.0
```