# How to use ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am new trying to learn programing and java, I am currently working in a program but I need help starting it, I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me.

I have to Implement a class IrregularPolygon that contains an array list of Point2D.Double objects.

The Point2D.Double class defines a point specified in double precision representing a location in (x, y) coordinate space. For example, Point2D.Double(2.5, 3.1) constructs and initializes a point at coordinates (2.5, 3.1).

I'm going to be Using this declarations as a starting point for my lab work.

```
import java.awt.geom.*;     // for Point2D.Double
import java.util.ArrayList; // for ArrayList

public class IrregularPolygon {
   private ArrayList <Point2D.Double> myPolygon;

   // constructors
   public IrregularPolygon() { }

   // public methods
   public void add(Point2D.Double aPoint) { }

   public double perimeter() { }

   public double area() { }
}
```

I would like some tips on how to Write methods that compute the perimeter and the area of a polygon. To compute the perimeter, and to compute the distance between adjacent points, and total up the distances. The area of a polygon with corners is the absolute value of:

Comment: Well, do you know what the perimeter and area are?

Comment: Start with the perimeter - that's the easy one. Can you traverse over the list of points? What have you tried?

Comment: i commented with what i have so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest `Math.hypot(point1.getX() - point2.getX(), point1.getY() - point2.getY())` for the distance of to adjacent points. For the perimeter (just as you stated) sum up all distances (don't forget to add the distance from the last to the first point). For the area see [How do I calculate the surface area of a 2d polygon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451426/how-do-i-calculate-the-surface-area-of-a-2d-polygon).

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can find this example helpful:

```
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class IrregularPolygon {
    private ArrayList<Point2D.Double> myPolygon;

    // constructors
    public IrregularPolygon() {
        this.myPolygon = new ArrayList<Point2D.Double>();
    }

    // public methods
    public void add(Point2D.Double aPoint) {
        this.myPolygon.add(aPoint);
    }

    public double perimeter() {
        // compute perimeter
        return 0;
    }

    public double area() {
        // compute area
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String result = "IrregularPolygon [";
        for (Point2D.Double point : myPolygon) {
            result += "|X: " + point.x + ". Y: " + point.y + "|";
        }
        result += "]";
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IrregularPolygon irregularPolygon = new IrregularPolygon();
        Point2D.Double point1 = new Point2D.Double(0, 2);
        Point2D.Double point2 = new Point2D.Double(2, 4);
        Point2D.Double point3 = new Point2D.Double(3, 5);

        irregularPolygon.add(point1);
        irregularPolygon.add(point2);
        irregularPolygon.add(point3);

        System.out.println(irregularPolygon.toString());
    }

}
```

You can find in the `toString()` method how to use the ArrayList in Java, as well as in the `add()` method, so the implementation of the methods `perimeter()` and `area()` just depends on the specs you have. You just need to extrapolate that methods to complete the class.

Hope it helps.

Clemencio Morales Lucas.

Answer (score 0):

this is what i have so far:

```
import java.awt.geom.*;   
import java.util.ArrayList; 

public class IrregularPolygon {
private ArrayList <Point2D.Double> myPolygon;


public IrregularPolygon() 
{ 
myPolygon = new ArrayList < Point2D.Double > ();
}

public void add(Point2D.Double aPoint)
{
myPolygon.add(aPoint);
}

public void print()
{
for (Object element : myPolygon)
{
      System.out.println(element);
  }
}

public double distance(Point2D pt)
{
   double distance = 0;
   x.distance(y);
   return distance;
}

public double perimeter()
{
double distance = 0;


for(int x = 0; x < aPoint; x++){  // cords given in groups might have to / by 2
    get.point();
    if(myPolygon[] != null){
         get.nextPoint();
          }
      else{
          distance += thePoint.distance(nextPoint)
          }
}

return distance;
}

public double area()
{ 
double area = 0;

return area;
}
}

//that's irregular polygon. this is polygon application

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

public class PolygonApplication
{
public static void main() {
String userInput;
int pointNumber = 1;
Point2D.Double nextPoint;
IrregularPolygon myPolygon = new IrregularPolygon();

do  {
     userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter x coordinate for point  " + pointNumber);
     if (userInput != null) {
     double x = Double.parseDouble(userInput);
     userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter y coordinate for point  " + 
             pointNumber);
if (userInput != null) {
                  double y = Double.parseDouble(userInput);
                  nextPoint = new Point2D.Double(x,y);
                  myPolygon.add(nextPoint);
                  pointNumber += 1;
}
}

} 
while (userInput != null);

myPolygon.print();
}
}
```