# Swift: SKShapeNode's proportion of view: how to determine?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skshapenode

[image]

In Swift, I would like to calculate how much in percentages the red SKShapeNode is of the (blue) SKScene layer. Can't find methods for determining shape area. Is there a way to calculate the area of SKShapeNode?

Comment: not a great solution: make a physics body form the shape's path and use the `area` property

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451426/how-do-i-calculate-the-surface-area-of-a-2d-polygon